# Decode AMR audio file in Android

Tags: android, decode, amr

Is there a way to decode an AMR audio file in Android and have access to the raw audio data? MediaCodec is only available for API 16 and above. I need something that will work on Android 2.2 and above.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no native API in 2.X platforms for doing this. You can use `ffmpeg` binaries in your application instead.

With a quick search I found [this precompiled version of `ffmpeg` for `Android` 2.2](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/detail?name=ffmpeg-1.0-android-arm.zip&can=2&q=).

You can place the executable it in your application `raw` resources folder and use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to execute it.

To convert an `AMR` file to `WAV` with `ffmpeg` you can do something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i file.amr file.wav
```

and to convert a wav to raw PCM you can do the following: (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11986279/303270))

```
ffmpeg -i file.wav -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le file.pcm
```

Comment: That's a very large package - over 9 mb. It's a full blown audio processing app. Overkill for my app which is only 2 mb in size.

Comment: Is there anyway to decode/convert AMR files to mp3/(any playable format)  in android kitkat 4.4.2 or higher version? If yes then can you please show some code snippet or any example to do that? Please help.