# How to convert audio file into wav pcm format

Tags: cordova, wav, pcm

I have developed android app using Phone Gap.

In the Application implement the voice recording method. Once recorded we received a audio file as wav format but i need the wav format as pcm 16bit 8000hz and channel is mono.But My wav file is in AMR band narrow format 32bit 8000hz mono.

Is there any possible for convert this format?

Comment: Is it jquery, cordova, Phone Gap question or mono question? It is somewhat confusing.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcondes It's a Phone gap

Comment: Maybe this could help ?

[Another question on StackOverflow][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986279/can-ffmpeg-convert-audio-from-raw-pcm-to-wav

I think that the only way to convert your file is using a server with ffmpeg.