NodeJS - efficiently and correctly convert from raw PCM to WAV at scale (without FFMPEG?)
I have a stream of raw PCM buffers I need to convert to playable WAV buffers.
@ffmpeg.wasm can convert an individual buffer in the stream well, but it's limited to executing 1 command at a time, so it won't work in a real-life streaming scenario (streams x concurrent users). We can use it as a reference to a conversion that outputs a good playable wav.
import { FFmpeg, createFFmpeg, fetchFile } from '@ffmpeg.wasm/main';

async pcmToWavFFMPEG(buffer: Buffer) {
    // bitDepth - PCM signed 16-bit little-endian
    const options = { sampleRate: '24k', channels: '1', bitDepth: 's16le' };

    this.ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', 'input.pcm', await fetchFile(buffer));

    await this.ffmpeg.run(
      '-f',
      options.bitDepth,
      '-ar',
      options.sampleRate,
      '-ac',
      options.channels,
      '-i',
      'input.pcm',
      'output.wav',
    );

    const wavBuffer = this.ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'output.wav');

    this.ffmpeg.FS('unlink', `input.pcm`);
    this.ffmpeg.FS('unlink', `output.wav`);

    return Buffer.from(wavBuffer);
  }

In order to get over the command execution limit, I've tried fluent-ffmpeg. I couldn't find a way to convert a single buffer, so I'm just passing the whole readable stream so that ffmpeg can convert all of its buffers to wav. The buffers I'm getting in on('data') aren't playable wav. The same is true for concatting the accumulated buffers in on('complete') - the result is not a playable wav.
import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg';
import internal from 'stream';

async pcmToWavFluentFFMPEG(
    readable: internal.Readable,
    callback: (chunk: Buffer) => void,
  ) {
    const options = { sampleRate: 24000, channels: 1, bitDepth: 's16le' };

    ffmpeg(readable)
      .inputFormat(options.bitDepth)
      .audioFrequency(options.sampleRate)
      .audioChannels(options.channels)
      .outputFormat('wav')
      .pipe()
      .on('data', callback);
  }

I've also tried using node-wav to convert each buffer individually. It manages to convert everything to playable wavs that sound close to the desired result, however for some reason they're extremely loud and sound a bit weird.
import wav from 'node-wav';

pcmToWavBad(buffer: Buffer) {
    const pcmData = new Int16Array(
      buffer.buffer,
      buffer.byteOffset,
      buffer.byteLength / Int16Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    );

    const channelData = [pcmData]; // assuming mono channel

    return wav.encode(channelData, { sampleRate: 24000, bitDepth: 16 });
  }

I've also tried wrapping the PCM as a WAV with wavefile without any actual conversion (which is redundant as PCM is contained as is in WAV), but it results in white noise:
import { WaveFile } from 'wavefile';

pcmToWav(buffer: Buffer) {
    const wav = new WaveFile();

    wav.fromScratch(1, 24000, '16', buffer); // 's16le' is invalid

    return Buffer.from(wav.toBuffer());
  }


I'm a little confused.  WAVE refers to a file format, not a data format.  WAVE files ordinarily contain PCM data.  The data doesn't need to be "converted" at all.

Don't I need to add a WAV header (and maybe other things?) in order for it to become a playable WAV? i.e. raw PCM can't be played on the browser. The conversion per se is probably redundant as you say.

Yes, you're correct.  In order to write PCM data to file, it has to become a WAV, which means it gets a WAVE header.  There are modules to manage WAVE files that do not require the extremely large ffmpeg module.  For example, wavefile.

That's good to hear. How would you do it? For instance this doesn't work for me (error):
pcmToWavHeader(buffer: Buffer) {
const wav = new WaveFile(buffer);
return Buffer.from(wav.toBuffer());

}

and neither does this (no error but not playable):
pcmToWavHeader(buffer: Buffer) {
const wav = new WaveFile();
wav.fromScratch(1, 24000, '16', buffer); // 's16le' is invalid

return Buffer.from(wav.toBuffer());

}

no luck with the wav-headers lib either.

Can you post a link to one of the files you created?

Here's one file, it should say "Hello Royi":
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Aca9lCVpvWDWp7ILgRLTCxEfDPQUjrE/view?usp=sharing

Your buffers look like 8-bit signed data.  The top byte is always 0.  Your comment says that it is big-endian; that could ALSO be the case, but if so, you will need to byte-swap it.  WAVE files are little-endian.  If I di byte-swapping, it looks more like an audio file, but there's still garbage in there.

I fixed the comment, I believe it's little-endian. If you'll notice I was actually passing 's16le' to the options. Passing 8-bit to wavefile plays something very loud and distorted, though passing 16-bit plays something silent / soft white noise. On the other hand, passing 8-bit to @ffmpeg.wasm resulted in a mess, 16-bit was what worked for me. I don't know how to read the buffer, I'm speaking from pure trial and error.

Any chance wavefile messes with the buffer? Maybe I could share the raw PCM buffer that resulted in a valid wav output when using @ffmpeg.wasm?

Here's a raw PCM buffer, just in case it helps shed some light:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WSfEiUcz1gwHhEvwddh5m4cYDR22Rjch/view?usp=sharing

OK, having looked a little closer, what's happening is that your 16-bit data is being treated as though they were 8-bit samples, padded with zeros.  So FFF7 is getting written as "F7 00 FF 00".  I don't know who is making that conversion

I'm checking it with the support of the 3rd party that's generating the PCM data. Is there anything that can be done about that on my end? How come ffmpeg is able to convert it nonetheless?

Also, according to the approved answer here, it seems ffmpeg can also be used to just add the wav header without any conversion, if you don't specify any output options. Or am I misunderstanding something?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11990796/5882529

Well, the ffmpeg command won't have any trouble, because it knows how to handle bytes.  There's probably something in your code that is causing a byte-to-word conversion.

Got it. Unfortunately there's nothing in my code whatsoever that does any coversion. I even have a small isolated repro that makes sure I'm not touching the buffers somewhere along the way. I'm only prepending a WAV header.
